Unable to Open Multiple Word Windows When Creating New Documents from Add-ins
I've developed an add-in for Microsoft Word. However, I've encountered an issue where I'm unable to open multiple Word windows when trying to create or open new documents from with the add-in enabled.
This happened with the latest update of MS Word from V2403 to V2404.
On click of a button when the user attempts to open a new document(in an MS Word window) containing the add-ins the new window does not seem to open. This is an occurrence we observed in the new update only and not in the previous updates.
Also another observed anomaly in this update is that, only in certain devices this issue occurs. The same accounts working in certain devices do not seem to work in certain devices.
We tried rolling back to 2403 (Build 17425.20176) from 2404 (Build 17531.20128). Yet the problem persisted.
The code used to open a new MS Word window:
window.open(`ms-word:ofe|u|${documentUrl}`);


A problem that correlates to a version or build is very likely a bug. Please raise an issue on the office-js repo.
